# Copy multiple Excel workbooks into one workbook

Tags: microsoft-excel, vba

I am trying to copy multiple Excel workbooks into a single workbook with each of the copied workbooks to have their own Tab.

I do not know how to use VB, so I have tried many VB scripts I found using Google, but for one reason or another (error 9, error 91, nothing happens, all workbooks gets copied into one tab) I have not managed to get it done.

Comment: VBA is used in excel. What scripts have you tried? What happened in each one? What didn't happen? How do you handle a workbook with multiple sheets?

Comment: You have accidentally created this question using an unregistered account and then created a new account and posted a comment as an answer. In order to regain control of your question please go to the contact form (superuser.com/contact) and select "I need to merge accounts" and enter your old account (http://superuser.com/users/556021/bryan-gervais) and your new account (http://superuser.com/users/556029/bryan-g) in the two boxes. This will allow you to edit, comment on and accept answers to your question.

Comment: Nothing seems to work fo rme when I try to merge my quest and my registered account, and when I try to give Votes whilke I am logged in, it asks me to log in again. Anyhow my Excel Problem is resolved with this code:       Sub GetSheets()
Path = "<INSERT PATH TO DIRECTORY HERE>"
Filename = Dir(Path & "*.xls*")
  Do While Filename <> ""
  Workbooks.Open Filename:=Path & Filename, ReadOnly:=True
    For Each Sheet In ActiveWorkbook.Sheets
    Sheet.Copy After:=ThisWorkbook.Sheets(1)
  Next Sheet
    Workbooks(Filename).Close
    Filename = Dir()
  Loop
End Sub

Answer (score 3):

If you don't have a lot of workbooks, you can do it manually by following [these instructions](http://www.extendoffice.com/documents/excel/456-combine-multiple-workbooks.html#copy).  Relevant excerpts:

- Right-click on the tab you want to move and choose `move or copy`
- Select the target book in the pull list
- Select the tab location where you would like it in the target book
- Click `ok`

If you have a lot of workbooks, you can automated it by following [these instructions.](http://www.extendoffice.com/documents/excel/456-combine-multiple-workbooks.html#copy)  Relevant excerpts:

- Put all the workbooks in the same directory and note the directory path
- Open the target workbook
- Click `Developer` -> `Visual Basic`
- In new window, click `Insert` -> `Module`
- Paste the following code:

  ```
  Sub GetSheets()
  Path = "<INSERT PATH TO DIRECTORY HERE>"
  Filename = Dir(Path & "*.xls*")
    Do While Filename <> ""
    Workbooks.Open Filename:=Path & Filename, ReadOnly:=True
      For Each Sheet In ActiveWorkbook.Sheets
      Sheet.Copy After:=ThisWorkbook.Sheets(1)
    Next Sheet
      Workbooks(Filename).Close
      Filename = Dir()
    Loop
  End Sub
  ```
- Replace the `Path` line with the full path to the directory with the workbooks
- Click the `green arrow button`to run the code and merge the workbooks.

Comment: I tried this and nothing happens. I get the Makros window, and choose Run, and then nothing further happens. No Errors either.

Comment: What version of Excel are you using?

Comment: And what is the full path to the directory containing the workbooks you wish to merge?

Comment: Thanks your script worked! Now I just Need to figure out how to make it automatically use a particular field with a 4 Digit number in each of the Excel Sheets that are being copied over, and with that 4 Digit number, rename each worksheet to each number respectively. Is there a way to edit the script to achieve this? BTW, I am not able to give you a Vote, it asks me to log in each time although I am logged in. maybe someone else can do it for me?

Comment: You can follow these instructions to dynamically rename the worksheets.  Probably easiest to add it as a second, separate script, though you can try integrating if you want: https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/kb/2790229

Comment: I tried it but get an error. Debug ShowsThis line as the error: rs.Name = "rs.Range("D6")"

Comment: Probably best to open a new question for the worksheet renaming.  Make sure to specify your version of Excel.

Answer (score 1):

This works -

```
    Sub CopyBooks()
    Application.ScreenUpdating = False
    Application.Calculation = xlManual

    Dim destinationWorkbook As Workbook
    Set destinationWorkbook = ThisWorkbook
    Dim sourceWorkbook As Workbook
    Dim sourceWorksheet As Worksheet
    Const path As String = "C:\your\path\"
    Dim file As Variant

    Dim currentSheets As Long
    currentSheets = destinationWorkbook.Sheets.Count

    file = Dir(path & "*.xl*")

    While file <> ""
        Set sourceWorkbook = Workbooks.Open(path & file)
            For Each sourceWorksheet In sourceWorkbook.Worksheets
                sourceWorksheet.Copy after:=destinationWorkbook.Worksheets(currentSheets)
                currentSheets = currentSheets + 1
            Next
            sourceWorkbook.Close savechanges:=False
            file = Dir
    Wend

    Application.Calculation = xlAutomatic
    Application.ScreenUpdating = True
    End Sub
```

Comment: I tried this and nothing happens. I get the Makros window, and choose Run, and then nothing further happens. No Errors either.

Comment: Make sure your path points to where your workbooks are